# Month wise aging report by SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

6 month aging report of the customers from today date.

Data in the table is like following:

```
    Customer    Date        Amount  
    AAA         3-Sep-13    1000  
    BBB         4-Jan-14    4000  
    BBB         5-Feb-14    1000  
    AAA         3-Dec-13    3000    
    CCC         7-Nov-13    800  
    DDD         15-Nov-13   1000  
    DDD         25-Jan-13   1000  
    CCC         8-Nov-13    1000
```

I need a SQL query to get the below results and heading should be in month and year

```
    Party name  Sep-13  Oct-13  Nov-13  Dec-13  Jan-14  Feb-14  Total Amount  
    AAA         1000      0     0       3000      0      0      4000  
    BBB         0         0     0      4000     1000     0      5000  
    CCC         0         0     1800    0       0        0      1800  
    DDD         0         0     1000    0       1000     0      2000
```

Comment: your photo is not clear. please put SQL code to create your table and also a few sample rows. It will be helpful.

Comment: And where is your attempt ?

Comment: is it possible through view or have to use the stored procedure ?

Comment: @haroon read here to learn [`How to ask a question on StackoverFlow`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Haroon forsy of all cant see a thing in this image you have posted in your question, secondly without knowing what is your data's current state it is hard to guide you if you need a stored procedure or a view for it. Please provide for information.

Answer (score 0):

This query will dynamically generate the output that you want.  However, because you don't have values for all periods, a NULL is inserted (which is valid).  If you want to make a value 0 instead of null, you'll have to modify the query and use the ISNULL function for each field.

```
CREATE TABLE testTable (
  Party NVARCHAR(20),
  [Date] SMALLDATETIME, --done like this to get a TOTAL heading
  Amount DECIMAL
)

INSERT INTO testTable VALUES 
('AAA','3-Sep-13',1000),
('BBB','4-Jan-14',4000),
('BBB','5-Feb-14',1000),
('AAA','3-Dec-13',3000),
('CCC','7-Nov-13',800),
('DDD','15-Nov-13',1000),
('DDD','25-Jan-13',1000)


INSERT INTO testTable
SELECT Party, '2054-12-31', SUM(Amount) [Amount]
FROM testTable
GROUP BY Party

DECLARE @columnHeadings NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @columnHeadings = COALESCE(
    @columnHeadings + ',[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [Date], 6) + ']',
    '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [Date], 6)+ ']'
  )
FROM testTable
GROUP BY [Date]
ORDER BY [Date]


DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = N'SELECT [party], ' + @columnHeadings + ' INTO ##output FROM ' +
  '( SELECT [Party], [Amount], CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [Date], 6) [Date] FROM testTable  ) [source]' +
  ' PIVOT ' +
  '( SUM(Amount) FOR [Date] IN (' + @columnHeadings +')) [pvt];'

EXEC(@sql) 

EXEC tempdb.sys.sp_rename '##output.[31 Dec 54]', 'Total', 'COLUMN'

SELECT * FROM ##output

DROP TABLE testTable
DROP TABLE ##output
```

Disclaimer: I'm not fond of this code.  But it works.

Comment: your result is Ok but the Heading is also showing date , it should be obly month and the year and data should also be month wise not date wise

Comment: That should be simple enough for you to change.  The bulk of the question is answered.  You just need to change the CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [Date], 6) part and have it format the date to your needs.